# Angular 1: Make a checkbox checked if object has property value true

Tags: angularjs

I have `ng-repeat` that prints various objects. There is also a checkbox. How do I make this checkbox to be checked by default if its object has property true? I tried to do this `ng-checked="{{item.completed}}"` but it didn't work well.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{item.completed}}" ng-model="toDoItemCheckbox">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `completed` property of `item` is boolean you simply have to pass this to ng-checked without the `{{}}`.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.completed" ng-model="toDoItemCheckbox">
```

ngChecked resolves the expression passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your object contains this property and that it is true indeed.

As `ng-checked` is an Angular directive, you can remove the `{{}}`:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.completed" ng-model="toDoItemCheckbox">
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/24579/)